# Setting up Google Apps

Tags: dns, google-apps

I have registered a domain (though there is no hosting yet, just name registration) and I am trying to set up google apps so that I can have email, but I cannot figure it out.  Is there something I am missing?  I feel like it should be easier than it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly set the MX records at your registrar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you proved domain ownership including a CNAME record in your DNS server? Just follow the instructions.

If you don't have access to your DNS server for adding records, and don't have a webserver where you can put a verification file I think you wont be able do setup e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the domain, you just need to follow the registration process, you will be taken through all the steps. If you got to the Admin Console you should have a message bar Top of the page with Verify Domain.

the best way to do it is to try the new Learning Center, http://learn.googleapps.com/.